# Python - remove all ' from a text file

Tags: python, syntax

I have a text file that contains the following data:

```
't''h''i''s''i''s''a''t''e''s''t''f''o''r''s''t''a''c''k''o''v''e''r''f''l''o''w'
```

I want to read the file, and remove all `'`s so the final result will look like this:

```
thisisatestforstackoverflow
```

I don't know if you need to write to another file or you can just change the current one, but I have tried to do it with `replace()` and I couldn't get it to work. If someone could write a small peace of code to show me how it works I will appreciate it!

Comment: If this is a one-off job, just use find-and-replace in a text editor.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: not Python, but at the command line it's just `sed "s/'//g" < input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re 
string = 't''h''i''s''i''s''a''t''e''s''t''f''o''r''s''t''a''c''k''o''v''e''r''f''l''o''w'
s = re.findall(r"[^']", string)
```

This will return a list:

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
['t', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 'a', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'f', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w']
```

and you can do anything with it.
Like:

```
''.join(s)
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
thisisatestforstackoverflow
```

Comment: Exactly what i need!, Thanks

Comment: string have a method called replace, you can use that.

Answer (score 3):

I like having these utility functions around:

```
def string_to_file(string, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(string)


def file_to_string(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()
```

With those, the answer becomes:

```
string_to_file(file_to_string(path).replace("'", ""), path)
```

Comment: You would really like Python's pathlib [`read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) and `write_text` methods.

Answer (score 0):

here is you answer:

```
str = 't''h''i''s''i''s''a''t''e''s''t''f''o''r''s''t''a''c''k''o''v''e''r''f''l''o''w'
str.replace("'", "")
print(str)
```

Comment: This answer isn't responsive to the OP's request to take data from a file (i.e. it doesn't start as a string). Ignoring that, oddly enough, your first line here is sufficient to stand alone: Python parses that statement into the single string `'thisisatestforstackoverflow'` automatically, for reasons I can't fathom.

Comment: In case of taking data from file just convert it line by line to string and do so.

Comment: fd = open(filename, 'rU')
chars = []
for line in fd:
    line = str(line)
    line.replace("'", "")